# split files with specific pattern

Tags: python, perl, awk

A file I work with is like

```
NAMES   n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
REGION  chr 1   100000
404 AAAAAAGA
992 TTTTTTTA
1146    CCCCGGCC
1727    CCCCCACC
1778    GCCCCCCC
```

My desired output is (please notice line two and how the numbers are there )

```
file1
 NAMES  n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
    REGION  chr 404 992
    404 AAAAAAGA
    992 TTTTTTTA

file2
 NAMES  n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
     REGION chr 1146    1778
1146 CCCCGGCC
1727 CCCCCACC
1778 GCCCCCCC
```

I have tried in awk

```
awk 'function print_vals() {
   fn="file" c;
   print hdr > fn;
   print "REGION  chr", sn, en >> fn;
   for (i in a)
      print a[i] >> fn;
} NR == 1 {
   hdr=$0;
   c=0;
   next
} NF==2 && $1 >= 1000000*c {
   if (c)
      print_vals();
   delete a;
   i=0;
   c++;
   sn=$1;
} NF==2 {
   a[++i]=$0;
   en=$1;
} END {
   print print_vals();
 }' file
```

For the sample data that worked  and I get the output but for the real data set it does not. The set is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6ukumbj08cwk99/arg_t1.gz?dl=0  It lloks like thi s

```
NAMES   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7  n8  n9  n10     n11     n12     n13     n14     n15     n16 $
REGION  chr     1   10000000
69  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
474     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
584     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
627     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
676     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
690     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
894     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
1104    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

with the output being - which is switched somehow...it is not the way it should be

```
NAMES   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7  n8  n9  n10     n11     n12     n13     n14     n15     n16 $
REGION  chr 69 999927
561321  AAAAAACAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCAAAACAACAAAACAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAACCAACA$
561362  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
562011  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
562029  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
562162  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
562171
```

could somebody tell me how I need to fix this or suggest another functio?

Comment: no diea anybod?

Comment: And what is the condition so that the files are divided.

Comment: 1000000 .. in the line NF==2 &&&

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` associative arrays are traversed in a non-determined order. Replace your

```
for (i in a)
```

by

```
n = i
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

---

To enclose your awk in a bash script you can use something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for file
do  awk -v file="$file" '....' "$file"
done
```

Make sure you run `chmod a+rx` on the script file. 
Also replace the line

```
fn="file" c;
```

in your awk script by

```
fn = c "_" file;
```

This line is how your new filename is built: the awk variable `file` is initially given as value the name of the
file being processed (the syntax is: awk -v variable=value). The awk variable `fn` is your
new filename, and is the variable `c` which holds the number, concatenated with the character `_` and the 
filename variable.

You can run this bash command with several files as arguments. They are processed by the awk
one by one.

---

Final result:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file
do awk -v file="$file" 'function print_vals() {
   fn = c "_" file;
   print hdr > fn;
   print "REGION  chr", sn, en >> fn;
   n = i
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      print a[i] >> fn;
 } NR == 1 {
   hdr=$0;
   c=0;
   next
 } NF==2 && $1 >= 1000000*c {
   if (c)
      print_vals();
   delete a;
   i=0;
   c++;
   sn=$1;
 } NF==2 {
   a[++i]=$0;
   en=$1;
 } END {
   print print_vals();
 }'  "$file"
done
```

Comment: could i modif the script also to make it executable from the command line and take in several files as arguments an process them? Is it possibl eto somehow specify a output name to the priogram?

Comment: @ktoui how would you want the output files named? The same as the input file with a `-1` suffix for example?

Comment: it would be you supply a argument and then your get somethign like 1_file1, and if the prefix is 2 it is 2-file1

Comment: the -1 suffix part would work

Comment: @ktoui I edited my answer. Note that there is a new option (-v file=...) in the awk command, and you must change a line in the awk '...' too.

Comment: could you post whole file..that woudl be giant

Comment: okay...how could ithen specify the prefix i use for the oupt/